# Scatter diagram not displaying correctly

Tags: r, scatter-plot

Below is code I'm using to display a scatter diagram :

```
xx = c('test1' , 'test2' , 'test3') 
yy = c(6 , 7 , 8) 
df <- data.frame(xx , yy)
ggplot(df, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) + geom_point(alpha = .01) + theme_bw()
```

Why are the values of the scatter diagram not being displayed ?

Here is the output :

[image]

Comment: what does alpha=0.01 do?

Comment: @Seth `alpha = 0.01` makes the alpha transparency so low that you can't really see the points.

Comment: @joran yes, increasing the value did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha parameter alters transparency. Increase alpha to see the points.